# Gmail MSGS sent as text MSGS

Tags: iphone, messages, spam

I’m receiving texts to my phone that are from a gmail email account and not from a phone number.

Any ideas on how to block them or how to move the into the spam folder?

The Gmail email addresses are made up of letters and numbers, or very crude, suggestive names. I didn’t open these creepy texts.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the from article "How to Block and Report Spam Calls and Text Messages" in the New York Times on [Aug 15, 2018](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/15/smarter-living/how-to-block-spam-calls-texts.html) <sub>See note below</sub>

> Reporting text messages is a little bit easier: No matter what phone you have, just forward the text message to SPAM (7726). Most carriers participate in a service that will use this information to try and block future spammers.

> ...

> Users of iPhones can report blue-bubble iMessages as spam with the Report Junk link that appears below messages from unknown users.

<sub>**Note**: you may need a subscription to access this article.</sub>